# persisting entities to mysql under symfony4 (duplicate key)

Tags: php, symfony, insert, on-duplicate-key

I know there are many questions like this already. However, none of the answers seem to fit my case...

I have a MySQL table such as the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personen;
CREATE TABLE personen (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    famname VARCHAR (70) NOT NULL default ' ',
    vorname VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL default ' ',
    titel VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL default ' ',
    titel2 VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL default ' ',
    titel3 VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL default ' ',
    geschlecht INTEGER NOT NULL default 1,  
    anrede2 VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL default ' ',
    bemerkung VARCHAR (191) NOT NULL default ' ',
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY `famname` (`famname`,`vorname`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`geschlecht`) REFERENCES `cdGeschlecht` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`formell`) REFERENCES `cdFormellInformell` (`id`)
)
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I use this table within Symfony4 for storage of the data of e "Personen" Entity with a number of fields. The unique key is defined properly in the Entity. In my "PersonenController" I have the code shown below. Essentially it is supposed to insert a new person if it does not yet exist in the database. However, when entering the data for a person that DOES already exist, I get the above error message, even though - at least that's what I think I specified - this should not occur. It might be that my query is incorrect (I find the usage of the expr() function somewhat exotic!). In case it is wrongly specified for the result required, it might of course return "null" even if the person already exists.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
// ... 
    $person  = new Personen();
    $personTest = new Personen();
    
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    
    // get / display formType
    $form = $this->createForm(PersonenType::class, $person, 
                   array('entityManager' => $em,));
    
    // when form is submitted...
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // existiert die Person schon in der DB?
        
        // creating a QueryBuilder instance
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        
        $qb->select('p') 
             ->from('App\Entity\Personen', 'p')
             ->where($qb->expr()->andX(
                 $qb->expr()->eq('p.famname', ':familyname'),
                 $qb->expr()->eq('p.vorname', ':firstname')
             ))
             ->setParameters(array('familyname' => '$famname',
                                   'firstname' => '$vorname',));
                    
        // retrieve the query from Querybuilder
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        
        // Execute Query
        $personTest = $query->getOneOrNullResult();
        
        // does the person already exist in the DB?
        if (!$personTest) {  
            $em->persist($person);
            $em->flush();
            $this->addFlash('notice', 'Person in DB gespeichert');
        }    
        // Person exists already...
        else { 
            $this->addFlash('notice', 'Person '.$famname.' '.$vorname.' '.'existiert schon in der Datenbank');
        }
        $nextAction = 'person_neu';
        return $this->redirectToRoute($nextAction);
    }
```

Comment: It looks like `$famname` and `$vorname` aren't set. Does that happen before the code that you included? I would assume you'd be getting those values from the form input.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest looking into the UniqueEntity validation that should handle cases like this. https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

Comment: Correct: $famname etc. were not set. I corrected the query-parameters like so: 
                 ->setParameters(array('familyname' => $person->getFamname(),
                                       'firstname' => $person->getVorname(),));